# Why i am getting !insertmacro: macro named "MUI_DEFAULT" not found error?

Tags: nsis

I am writing a script in for my installer.i am using ultra modern ui for better look .so i have used following code.
But I am getting error insermacro mui_default not found;

Code:

```
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT MUI_TEXT_COLOR FFFFFF
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT MUI_BGCOLOR 3d66ab
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_TEXT_LIGHTCOLOR FFFF00
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_BRANDINGTEXTFRONTCOLOR 8b8ca4
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_BRANDINGTEXTBACKCOLOR eeeef3
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_LEFTIMAGE_BMP \
    "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UltraModernUI\Skins\blue\LeftBranding.bmp"
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_HEADERIMAGE_BMP \
    "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UltraModernUI\Skins\blue\Header.bmp"
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_BOTTOMIMAGE_BMP \
    "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UltraModernUI\Skins\blue\BtmImg.bmp"
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT MUI_ICON \
    "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\UltraModernUI\Icon.ico"
!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT MUI_UNICON \
    "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\UltraModernUI\UnIcon.ico"
```

Comment: Please add some details - what error you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That macro only works after `!include "UMUI.nsh"` but for the global settings you can probably just use a define:

```
!define MUI_TEXT_COLOR FFFFFF
...
!define  UMUI_BRANDINGTEXTBACKCOLOR eeeef3

!include "UMUI.nsh"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_...
```